Web Application in IIS 10 Always Running Not Working (Blazor Web Server)
IIS Stops after some hours 
Worker application in IIS 10 stops after some hours of inactivity as you can see in the image.
I am almost certain I have to Install **Applicaton Initialization ** module, right?
And then restart the Worker and website.
But, do I have to change my code inside the app or somewhere else?
Thanks in advance
I have set up these settings:
IIS - Your App Pool - Start Mode - Always Running
IIS - Your App Pool - Idle Time-out - 0
IIS - Your App - Advanced Settings - Preload Enabled - True
Currently I did not
Install Application Initialization Module (IIS)
and did not update my Blazor app code or elsewhere

It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, do you get related error messages in Event Viewer?

You are on the right path. By default IIS timeouts all application after they are iddle, this is the correct behaviour to save on resources, etc... Look into this article on how to keep your application running always.
Keep IIS application always running
You do not have to change anything on your app. I have used this artcile to host my website with no problems.
